# How to read multi-tab excel file in PHP?

Tags: php, excel

I have one excel file and I want to read it using PHP code.

In current excel file there are 3 tabs lets say tab1, tab2 & tab3.

```
tab1 
<Content>

tab2 
<Content>

tab3
<Content>
```

How can I read  a tab and write its content on file (with tab name).

Comment: You can use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Can it read multi-tab file also?

Comment: Yes, with getSheet()

Comment: use one of the many avaiable plugins for excel files and ofcourse you should be able to read multi tabs, each plugin handles it different so read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel](http://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Here is a helpful site how to use it:

http://www.techchattr.com/how-to-read-excel-files-with-php

or

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/05-Reader-Options.md

Comment: I tried to use muti tab-file but i found there is no desired output.  <?php
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile("sample.xlsx");
$excelReader->setLoadAllSheets();
print_r($excelReader);
?>